# Gitlab deploy not updating releases

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So first I use phpstorm and truncated the database. Next I imported a similar database but updated one through sql script.

Then I changed the url of the gitlab repository.
I changed the url in config file of .git folder

Now every deploy to the server succeeds but no files are uploaded changed or whatsoever.

I don’t understand. If I change the host in capistrano file the deploy fails but if I make a change in some other file, like in the public_html folder the deploy succeeds but the file on the server remains the same.

What could this possibly be?